# How to include non executable stm32 library in IAR?

Tags: stm32, iar, lib

I've compiled a project as a library for stm32 using iar, after adding the .a file the linker gives a warning that the used functions are declared implicity.
The function accepts a pointer to input buffer and return a pointer to output buffer, when assiging a pointer to save the return address the complier gives an error that a value of intcan't be assigned to pointer.

What could be the error, or. Is there something missing in the way of adding lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `.h` file as well with the data structures & function prototypes.

Comment: The library contains the header file in addition to function definitions, should I re-include them

Comment: Of course, in every file you use this library functions or data